# d3js 4 get coordinate of path transition

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

I would like to know if animated path transition can return the last drawn position ? 
..through *attrTween* we can get tween range [0-1] but a curve pos ??

ex:

```
 path
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", t1 + " " + t1)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", t1)
    .transition(d3.transition()
                            .duration(lap)
                            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                            .attrTween( "e", function(d) {
                                    return function( t ) {}})
   .attr("stroke-dashoffset",0)
```

thank's

Answer (score 0):

The tween and its factory could be defined like this:

```
function tween (t) {
    var totalLength = this.getTotalLength();
    //a SVGPoint object with x/y properties
    var position = this.getPointAtLength(total * t);
    //...do something
}

function tweenFactory (d) {
    return tween.bind(this);
}
```

If the path is already present in the DOM at the time the factory is executed and the path length does not change, the computation of `totalLength` can obviously be moved to the factory function.`

Comment: Merci ! I've switched attrTween to tween then  put back the return function( t ) and it work.